# How to map non related JPA entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

hi i am using hibernate 5.4.32. i have two JPA entities which does not have any association between them . Is there any way i can get the results in my entity.

**Entity 1**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "XYZ_EC")
public class LoanOrder{
    @Id 
    UUID id; 
  
    public List<DDLTable> ddlTables; // select TABLE_NAME, DESCRIPTION, FILTER_TYPE from DDLTable where TABLE_NAME = 'ABC', this is the query i want to be executed . 
    //LoanOrder Entity does not have any column to map to DDL entity.
```

**Entity 2**

```
@Table(name = "DDL_TABLE")
@Entity
public class DDLTable implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "TABLE_NAME")
    private String tableName;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
    private String description;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "FILTER_TYPE")
    private String filterType;
}
```

Comment: You can use `PostConstruct` in `LoadOrder` entity and fetch and set whatever data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though it is not very correct and clean what you are trying to achieve (it would be better to use a third class, a `DTO` to hold all the data you want from both Entities), you can try the following:

At `LoanOrder` Entity, mark the `ddlTables` list as transient in order JPA to ignore it and not try to map this field to a database column.

```
@Transient
public List<DDLTable> ddlTables;
```

Then supposedly you have somewhere a `@Service` class which deals with database queries etc

```
@Service
public class LoanOrderService {

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;

    public LoanOrder loadSomething() {
        List<DDLTable> ddlTables = em.createQuery("SELECT ddl FROM DDLTable ddl WHERE ddl.tableName = 'ABC'", DDLTable.class).getResultList();

        //load a `LoanOrder` object from database similarly and set its ddlTables list to the one loaded above.
        LoanOrder loanOrder = ....; // load from database or create new depends on what you want to do
        loanOrder.setDdlTables(ddlTables);
        return loanOrder;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `@JoinFormula`

```
@OneToMany
@JoinFormula("TABLE_NAME = 'ABC'")
public List<DDLTable> ddlTables;
```

Please find more information in the documentation:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-JoinFormula